# justify-content: space-around; NO FUNCIONA

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, navbar

soy nuevo en esto y sobretodo en React y no logro hacer que me funcione justify-content: space-around; o justify-content: space-between;

Mi componente:

```
import React from "react";
import { Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown, FormControl, Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import "../css/navigation.css";

class Navigation extends React.Component {
 render(){
   return(
     <div className="container-fluid">
     <Navbar className= "Navbareta" bg="" variant="">
   <Nav className="navbarbuttons">
     <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
     <Nav.Link href="#home">News</Nav.Link>
     <Nav.Link href="#features">Tampa Bay</Nav.Link>
     <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Team</Nav.Link>
     <Nav.Link href="#pricing">SB</Nav.Link>
   </Nav>
 </Navbar>
</div>

   )
 }
} 
export default Navigation;
```

Su css:

```
.container-fluid{
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}

.Navbareta{
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.navbarbuttons a{
  color: black;
}
```

Me quedan todos los botones de la navbar en el centro.
Tampoco logro que la navbar ocupe el 100% , deja unos pequeños espacios en cada borde de la pagina.

Si alguno me puede ayudar se lo agradeceria.
Saludos.

Comment: tienes que añadir `display: flex` al `Nav` y no `container-fluid`

Comment: Si ya estás utilizando `react-bootstrap` porque no utilizas los [componentes de layout](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/) que te ofrecen?

Comment: Coloca una imagen de lo que tienes y un ejemplo de lo que quieres, te puedo apoyar